# Vagrant VBoxManage: error: AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, amd-processor

Im using Ubuntu 20.04 server.
I wanna use vagrant to run couple of vbox machine to deploy ceph as test but the `vagrant up` command shows this error.
None of solutions on StackOverflow works.

```
model name      : AMD EPYC 7502P 32-Core Processor
```

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

```
Command: ["startvm", "b52bdf58-d243-4f24-8984-0436d13ea4b5", "--type", "headless"]
```

```
Stderr: VBoxManage: error: AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Comment: I add "--hwvirtex", "off" to modifyvm but it wont work

Comment: `error: AMD-V is not available` means that the virtualisation instructions set of your CPU is disabled. You have to enable it inside the bios.

Comment: its a VM in Vmware esxi,

Comment: AMD-V should be enabled in vmware esxi. am i right??

Answer (score 1):

After searching I came across to this Idea to Enable Nested-VT in Vmware ESXI.
it can be done in 2 way first ssh to wmware server and edit this parameter in
/etc/vmware/config or you can do it from vmware Vsphare
.

1. add 'vhv.enable = true' to /etc/vmware/config
   or
2. do it in wmware vsphare panel

follow this ref -->
https://www.cloudshare.com/blog/vmware-esxi-nested-virtualization/